Gtk4 GObject, ClosureMarshal how can I use "return value"?
"A GClosure represents a callback supplied by the programmer.
It will generally comprise a function of some kind and a marshaller used to call it. It is the responsibility of the marshaller to convert the arguments for the invocation from GValues into a suitable form, perform the callback on the converted arguments, and transform the return value back into a GValue."
This is how it is in the documentation.
To test and try it out, I wrote a small program that is intended to use the following structure:
struct GClosure {
  guint in_marshal : 1;
  guint is_invalid : 1;
  void (* marshal) (
    GClosure* closure,
    GValue* return_value,
    guint n_param_values,
    const GValue* param_values,
    gpointer invocation_hint,
    gpointer marshal_data
  );
}

My problem is that I have not yet managed to find a way to use "return-value".
Unfortunately, all my previous attempts ended with a memory error.
Here is the Script:
 
#include<gtk/gtk.h>

typedef struct _MyClosure 
{
    GClosure closure;
    int closure_data;
} MyClosure;

static void
my_closure_finalize(gpointer notify_data, GClosure *closure)
{
    MyClosure * my_closure = (MyClosure*)closure;
    printf("Finalizing closure with closure_data: %d\n",my_closure->closure_data);
}

GValue* my_callback(GClosure *closure, const GValue *param_values)

{   
    MyClosure *my_closure = (MyClosure*)closure;
    printf("In Callback with closure_data. %d\n", my_closure->closure_data);
    if (&param_values[0] != NULL) 
    {
    printf("In Callback with value: %s\n", g_value_get_string(&param_values[0]));
    }
        /* Return */
    GValue value = G_VALUE_INIT;
    g_value_init(&value, G_TYPE_STRING);
    g_value_set_static_string(&value, "The End");
    /* edit */
    printf("Return from Callback %s\n",g_value_get_string(&value));
    return value;

}

static void
my_closure_marshal(GClosure *closure, 
        GValue *return_value, 
        guint n_params_values, 
        const GValue *param_values, 
        gpointer invocation_hint, 
        gpointer marshal_data)
{
    MyClosure *my_closure = (MyClosure*)closure;
    printf("mashalling closure with closure_data. %d\n", my_closure->closure_data);
    if (&param_values[0] != NULL) 
    {
        printf("Callback called with value: %s\n", g_value_get_string(&param_values[0]));
    }
   /* edit */    
  *return_value = my_callback(closure,param_values);
        // Segmentation fault (core dumped)
        /*
        printf("after Callback\n");
        GType type = G_VALUE_TYPE(return_value);
        g_print("Return type %s\n",g_type_name(type));
        g_print("Result in Mashaller %s\n",g_value_get_string(return_value));
        */

}   

MyClosure *
my_closure_new(gpointer data)
{
    GClosure *closure;
    MyClosure *my_closure;
    closure = g_closure_new_simple(sizeof(MyClosure), data);
    my_closure = (MyClosure*)closure;
    my_closure->closure_data = 42; 
    g_closure_add_finalize_notifier(closure,NULL, my_closure_finalize);
    g_closure_set_marshal(closure, my_closure_marshal); 
    return my_closure;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MyClosure *my_closure = my_closure_new(NULL);
       
    GValue* return_value;
    GValue value = G_VALUE_INIT;
    g_value_init(&value, G_TYPE_STRING);
    g_value_set_string(&value, "Hello");

    g_closure_invoke((GClosure*)my_closure,return_value, 1,&value , NULL);

    /* How can I further process here "return_value" */
    /*It should be the string "The End". */
    
    g_closure_unref((GClosure*)my_closure);

    return 0;
}

Does anyone have an idea?
Having edited according to the proposal of 'Bodo',
I get the following result:
mashalling closure with closure_data. 42
Callback called with value: Hello
In Callback with closure_data. 42
In Callback with value: Hello
Return from Callback The End
Segmentation fault (core dumped)


I suggest to run your code in a debugger to find out where exactly ithe segmentation fault occurs. Then set a breakpoint and check the values of the variables. I also suggest to copy&paste the modified code to make it easier for someone to compile and run it.

GValue* return_value means that this argument must be a pointer to a variable of type GValue. As with any pointer, to return a value you can't modify the pointer inside the function, but you have to store the value at the location the pointer points to.
Something like
GValue my_callback(GClosure *closure, const GValue *param_values)

{   
    MyClosure *my_closure = (MyClosure*)closure;
    printf("In Callback with closure_data. %d\n", my_closure->closure_data);
    if (&param_values[0] != NULL) 
    {
    printf("In Callback with value: %s\n", g_value_get_string(&param_values[0]));
    }
        /* Return */
    GValue value = G_VALUE_INIT;
    g_value_init(&value, G_TYPE_STRING);
    g_value_set_static_string(&value, "The End");

    return value;
}

static void
my_closure_marshal(GClosure *closure, 
        GValue *return_value, 
        guint n_params_values, 
        const GValue *param_values, 
        gpointer invocation_hint, 
        gpointer marshal_data)
{
    MyClosure *my_closure = (MyClosure*)closure;
    printf("mashalling closure with closure_data. %d\n", my_closure->closure_data);
    if (&param_values[0] != NULL) 
    {
        printf("Callback called with value: %s\n", g_value_get_string(&param_values[0]));
    }
    *return_value = my_callback(closure,param_values);
        GType type = G_VALUE_TYPE(return_value);
    g_print("Return type %s\n",g_type_name(type));
        g_print("Result in Mashaller %s\n",g_value_get_string(return_value));
}   

This code is untested.

The original function my_callback contains undefined behavior because it returns the address of the local variable value:
GValue* my_callback(GClosure *closure, const GValue *param_values)

{   
    /* ... */
        /* Return */
    GValue value = G_VALUE_INIT;
    /* ... */
    GValue *ret = &value;
    return ret;
}


Thank you, unfortunately it still does not work.

@Holger In which way exactly does it not work? Please edit your question, state that you edited it, add the modified code based on my answer and show the actual and expected output. Make sure you compile it with all warnings enabled and fix warnings you might get. Or show the warnings if you don't know how to fix them.

I edited the question according to your recommendations.
